# Rxjs, return Type

Tags: rxjs

I have probleme with that code. I need to get date in depends condition, but in subscribe I get not the correct type.

```
of (''). pipe (
       takeUntil (this.destroyer $),
       switchMap (() => {
         if (this.isITVPlatformClient) {
           // return FirstType
           return this.firstService.GetData ();
         } else {
           // return [SecondType | ThirdType]
           return forkJoin (
             this.secondService.GetData2 (),
             this.secondService.GetData3 ()
           );
         }
       })
     ) .subscribe (([first, second]) => {
       console.log (first); // type FirstType | SecondType
       console.log (second); // type FirstType | ThirdType
     });


    

}
```

How I can refactor this part of code for getting first variable with <FirstType | SecondType> interface and second variable with  interface:

```
... subscribe (([first, second]) => {
       console.log (first); // type FirstType | SecondType
       console.log (second); // type ThirdType
     });
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What is the desired result?

Comment: @DanielB question was about types. I need that in first variable gets data with <FirstType | SecondType> interface and second variable gets data with <ThirdType> interface

Comment: Will the first, second, third return all have different return types?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the 'FirstType' will not return an array type, you can check the final result if it is an array or not and do corresponding handling.

```js
    of('').pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroyer$),
      switchMap(() => {
        if (this.isITVPlatformClient) {
          // return FirstType
          return of('1');
        } else {
          // return [SecondType | ThirdType]
          return forkJoin([
            of({'test': 123}),
            of('3')
          ])
        }
      })
    ).subscribe((result) => {
      var isArray = Array.isArray(result);

      if (isArray) {
        console.log(result[0]); // type SecondType
        console.log(result[1]); // type ThirdType
      } else {
        console.log(result); // type FirstType
      }
    });
```